# How to add rounded borders to rounded images (made rounded with border-radius)

Tags: css

I've set profile images to show "rounded". In order to achieve that I've set border-radius to 50%.

When I try to add a border to that rounded image, (ie. `border:1px black solid;`), it doesn't follow the rounded pattern, but it just add a border to the square image.

How may I add a rounded border ?

Comment: example?  You could use jsfiddle/cssdesk/jsbin/dabblet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/72Knb/ Show you code, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/XKFrc/

Comment: The way I got around it was by having an outer element with a `border-radius` and then apply a similar `border-radius` to the image as a child of the parent node. Not ideal, but CSS ftw. If you were looking to support webkit only, i'd say check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-webkit-mask

Comment: You´re right. It didn´t worked because I used .picture {} instead of .picture img {}. THANKS!!! Please post it as a reply so I can accept it. Because the jsfiddle example is the correct way to do it. At least it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to apply the border-radius to the same element that gets the border and the rounded corners.

@ben c.taylor : I don't know if it's a hack, but it works on Chrome at least, just tested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `background-image` property to set the image as a background image of a div element for example. Then apply `border-radius` to this.

Dont forget your browser prefixes though!

Answer (score -2):

images doesen't support the border-radius,html5 canvas images too.
try it with a div with background-image.
example:

> < div style="background-image: url('profilpic.png'); border-radius:
>   10px; *(etc...)*">

it's will have border-radius

Comment: @EamonNerbonne - Really? http://jsfiddle.net/XKFrc/. Seems to work fine in most browsers.

Comment: To unconfuse the comments: j08691 replied to a comment while I deleted it; it concerned a previous edit of the answer; _and_ apparently the bug has been fixed.